# Add CSS to text without tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<td colspan="4" valign="top">
  <label for="state_1" id="state_1">
        Text:
  </label>
    another text
 </td>
```

Can i add css to "another text" without a html tag o id/class on td class?

Comment: `td:not(label) {}` can be used (just for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs you sure? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/EXoWpq

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `td *:not(label)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you sure, too? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/zzpZJV

Comment: @MichaelCoker not sure, hence the question mark

Comment: I can confirm that neither suggestion works in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Actually, you can't because it isn't wrapped in another element. Michael's example is a bit off because CSS won't get applied to the td regardless if it isn't in a table (weird quirk), but you also can't do what you suggest. `td:not(label)` will apply to any `td` that isn't a `label` (which is all of them). That means the `td` will be red, which the `label` will still inherit. `td *:not(label)` (per Michael's example) will not apply to anything, because the text isn't an element that can be selected with `*`.

Comment: `td *:not(label)` will only work if the text was wrapped in some other element, like a span. `td *:not(label)` and `td :not(label)` are functionally equivalent, neither will work. You can't select a text node.

Comment: @samanime Shouldn't it autowrap into a `<p>`?

Comment: @Greg Nope. Some frameworks/editors (TinyMCE used by WordPress jumps to mind) will auto-wrap in `<p>` tags, but most of the time things shouldn't be auto-wrapping anything in anything because it can have unintended consequences. Something like `<p>ABC</p>` is actually a paragraph `Element` wrapped around a text `Node`. The text is it's own thing, even if wrapped in a paragraph.

Comment: @samanime So used to Asp.Net Web-Forms or other frameworks modifying I suppose, good to know.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: not easily.

Longer answer: yes, but if you don't want the style to also apply to the `<label>`, you'll need to also negate those style changes.

While it would definitely be easier to just wrap the text in a `<span>` and target it with `td span` as the CSS selector, you could apply CSS to `td`, and then "undo" those changes to `td label`:

```
td {
  color: red;
}

td label {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first target the `td` you want. Since you don't want to add an id or class to it, you'll have to use general selectors, i.e `td` or `table tr td`. In order to only affect the text and not the label, you'll have to "undo" the styles you add to the td text:

```
td {
  color: red;
}
td label {
  color: black;
}
```

If you have other tags inside the `td` in addition to the label, you'll have to exclude those as well.

Comment: @Chris we commented at the same time. It's not a duplicate, it's just an easy question to answer....You shouldn't downvote a legit answer because it's "duplicate". Downvoting is for answers that don't answer the question or suggest something that's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you can target "td" in your css, but it will affect  as well since css works in cascade, so you'll have to write extra css to overwrite it. Like so :

```
td{
  color: red;
} 
td label{
  color: black;
}
```